WinUI 3 Application Fails to Run Due to System.ArgumentException in InitializeComponent
I have a winui3 project, and when I run it, it stops and show this
Call stack :
App1.dll!App1.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__4_2(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
Debugging logs :
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll
WinRT information: Not implemented

The program '[15308] App1.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

Relevant code :
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1 {
    public sealed partial class App : Application {
        public static MainWindow m_window = new();

        public App() {
            // init
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

I found out that i can't run this line this.InitializeComponent();

You do not show the code about the exception. Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

You can try running the command to make sure the SDK has the components available:
Using the command-line or .NET CLI:
dotnet add package Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT --version 2.0.8

This is needed plus additional components (based on the step 3): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/create-winrt-component-winui-cswinrt#author-your-cwinrt-component-using-the-windows-app-sdk
When creating the New Project, selecting the C++ Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop) there should be a pch.h file where the WinRT is implemented:
#include <winrt/WinUIComponentCs.h>
#include <winrt/WinUIComponentCs.WinUIComponentCs_XamlTypeInfo.h>

The debug again

Thank you for your help , it works great on new project but i not on my old files , it said file .winmd not exist , do you have any ideas ?

@tribeti Is it necessary to do something for a new WinUI3 project?

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT the new project is Class Library (WinUI 3 in Desktop) template while the old one is Blank App template

@tribeti Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?
